# WSO2 APIM with IS as KM - Jaggery Service Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are working on delivering a deployment of two WSO2 components - API Manager 3.0.0 and Identity Server 5.9.0 (which acts as Key Manager for APIM). For last few weeks everything worked fairly ok until today (or max few days ago) - suddenly we are getting following error when we try to log in to APIM Publisher:

```
ERROR {Jaggery service for token introspection} - {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
```

At same time publisher just keeps redirecting somewhere with an error message in the the browser logs:

```
Something went wrong while introspecting the token!!
```

Both components run on same virtual machine with offset for IS-as-KM set to 2. Datasources are OracleDB with full range of permissions for sake of testing.

Entire thing is handled using FQDN with wildcard certificate added to keystore.

Any idea about what this could be related to?

Comment: It seems that changing main admin user password just through Identity Server wasn't enough, it has to be changed in deployment.toml too. Problem solved.

Comment: Happened to me just a few minutes ago. I didn't expect this to be the cause...

Comment: @macmacmac Can you post what you did as an answer so that it will be helpful to anyone encountering the same in future.